# regex: Match specific characters is specific position in string

Tags: python, regex, string

Hi guys I am new with Regex I trying to define a pattern(python) in the following string:

```
\\xxxx\bbbbb\ccccc\mmmmmm\ooooooo\Snapshot\llllllllllllllllllll.png
```

`S**p*ho*` I need all words that have in position:

- 0: have S
- 1: any letter
- 2: any letter
- 3: have p or P
- 4: any letter
- 5: have h or H
- 6: have o or O
- 7: any letter

I am using:

```
res = re.findall(r'[S]\p{L}\p{L}\p{L}\p{L}\p{L}\p{L}\p{L}', str_3.upper())
```

But I also need specific characters in positions 0,3,5,6.

Thanks,

Comment: You're making it way harder than it is.  To match the letter S, you just include the letter S,  `r'S..[Pp].[Hh][Oo].'`.

Comment: `re.findall('(S[A-Za-z]{2}[Pp][A-Za-z][Hh][Oo][A-Za-z])', str_3)` . Don't use `upper` if you're checking both "P" and "p".

Comment: @TimRoberts I agree in general; yes, `S` is better than `[S]`. But `.` is not a valid translation for "any letter"; OP has it correct there (or at least they would if Python supported `\p`); and `0` is definitely not valid for `[oO]`.

Comment: However if you `pip install regex` and `import regex as re`, you can use `\p{L}` just fine.

Comment: No need for `regex`, use `[^\W\d_]` to match any Unicode letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my first time answering a question, but I'll give it my best shot.
Please try the following pattern and let me know if it helps.

```
S\p{L}\p{L}[pP]\p{L}[hH][oO]\p{L}
```

Here's an explanation for each part:

`S` matches exactly S.

`\p{L}` matches any kind of letter from any language.

`[pP]` matches p or P.

`[hH]` matches h or H.

`[oO]` matches o or O.

If `\p{L}` doesn't work, you can try to replace it with `[a-zA-Z]` which will match any lowercase or uppercase letter from a to z.